# The static field Context.ALARM_SERVICE should be accessed in a static way

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sms, alarmmanager

this app is running. but i don't understand why i'm getting that warning. i hope you can provide a solution. thank you!

java code:

```
     /*final int*/ mId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
     i.putExtra("com.somitsolutions.android.smsscheduler.id", mId);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)      
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);  <<-- this is where i get the warning
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), mId, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

i'm a beginner by the way so i'm not really sure if these codes will help you understand and answer. :)

Comment: @SuperUser I'm not sure "Forget about warnings" is a good message to send. Sure, often times they can be ignored but it is still good to know why you get them and which ones to worry about.

Comment: @SuperUser - he will run into trouble in the future if he does that.

Comment: @codeMagic Sorry about that but most of times warnings are not important.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace 
getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE
with 
Context.ALARM_SERVICE
```

you are trying to access a static field present in the Context class using an instance of Context which is incorrect".

Comment: i did exactly what you said but i still get it the same message.

Answer (score 0):

ALARM_SERVICE is a static of Context. getApplicationContext() passes you an instance of Context. So the compiler is trying to say access the variable "ALARM_SERVICE" in a static way.

Context.ALARM_SERVICE

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [ContextWrapper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.0mBase) class source code :

```
  ....
  Context mBase;
  ....
    @Override
     public Context getApplicationContext() {

        return mBase.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

means  `getApplicationContext()` method return an instance of Context class. In your case you are accessing `ALARM_SERVICE` property as `getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE` which means accessing static property using instance so warning suggest you no need to use instance for accessing static properties of class. you can do it as using class name :

```
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Adt suggested the same thing. i don't understand why i'm still getting it.